# How to get my import statement right that is nested inside a library folder

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class SampleTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("file.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
        pkg.close();
    }

}
```

Both import statement still tells me it does not exist.

I tried:

1. Adding `poi-bin-3.15-20160924.zip` to Libraries|Add JAR/Folder, it has all the jar including the `poi-ooxml-3.15.jar`
2. Adding folder of `poi-bin-3.15-20160924` to the same place

Which is the common solutions to all the *duplicate* questions but it doesn't solve my problem, so how do I add the `Apache Poi` correctly which I can import successfully in my code.

Or can someone just give me a fully working `Netbean` project folder which already has the `Apache Poi` inside.

**UPDATE**

My friend gave me an idea of will my import understand if its nested inside a folder. So after I added all the jar directly to my libraries, it worked. So now my question is how do I modify my import statement so that they know I am referring to `Apache Poi(folder)|poi-bin-3.15-20160924.zip|poi-ooxml-3.15.jar`

Comment: Are you sure that Netbeans can read a jar from inside a zip? For most systems (I don't know netbeans), you'd unzip the bin jar, and point at the jars you unpacked

Comment: @Gagravarr The 2nd method I tried was unzip the bin and place it in the the Libraries folder, but it didn't work as well.